# Current limiter problem

Tags: circuit-design, bjt, current-limiting, failure-mode

I am designing the following circuit to limit current inrush to a device on startup (to about 1.5 amps over about 3 seconds).  Rload is just for testing, the actual load is a bunch caps at 56v, but I have not tested with those yet.  Everything simulates fine.  I have bread-boarded the circuit and if I apply 12vdc everything matches the simulation.  If I apply 48vdc, it fails.  I see about 4 amps, which is the overload limit of my power source and stuff gets hot pretty quick. It doesn't appear to be damaging anything, because I can go back to 12vdc and it goes back to about 1.5 amps.  I assume it some kind of thermal runaway, but everything I have tried to fixed it has had little effect.  The base resistors do not seem to make a difference.  Before I added the emitter (ballast) resistors, I was blowing up transistors, so those seem to work.

So I expect this circuit to limit the current in the load to 1.5a when I apply 56v.  It doesn't, and I don't know why.  It works fine when I apply 12v.

Any ideas what is going wrong here?

[image: limiter]

Comment: Is this an actual design? If so, let's see how you approached the design. If not, and it's just a "borrowed and adapted by hunt and peck" design, then I think we need to hear a lot more about what you are actually trying to achieve.

Comment: How are you heatsinking those transistors? Even at 1.5A (0.5A each) they are dissipating 20W each, What thermal resistance  (degrees/watt) is the heatsink rated for? What junction temperature does that give, and do they work at that temperatuce?

Comment: Can you expand on "it fails" - fails how? does what? doesn't do what ? What is the end current once charged? - you have (3 x 1R //) + 1 R = 1.333 Ohm series and a 3.85 Ohm load  so about 25% losses in the series R's. Is that acceptable. || At 48V are the transistor safe areas violated?

Comment: Yes it is a design.

Comment: I originally started with 12 C/W, but the transistors barely heated during a test, so I changed to 26 C/W so I could feel if the device had passed any current during a test (a test last about 10 seconds).

Comment: Failure is that it should be limiting the current to 1.5-ish amps, but it acts as a short. The final current will end up being around 1/4 amp.  This circuit is to replace a set of fixed resistors. I thought everything was in a safe area, but apparently I missed something.

Comment: 26C/W times 20W = dead transistors.

Comment: Yes for the steady state, but for a 10 second test, they only get warm with the 26s (no temp change with the 12s).  Also after a test with the 26s at 48v, I can run a test with 12 volts and everything works fine (exactly the same response as before the test with 48v).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found it.  It looks like I am violating the the forward bias safe operating area.  The graph shows a current limit of about 0.3 Amps at 48 V (about 15W), well less than what I was designing for and more in line with what I was observing. Thanks Russell McMahon.